# How can I have multiple C++ timer callbacks of the same type in a single process?

Tags: c++, linux, timer

I'm currently using `setitimer()` to implement timeouts in my program, but I need multiple timeouts to be counting down simultaneously.  The documentation for [Setting an Alarm](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-an-Alarm.html) mentions that

> you can only have one timer of each kind set at any given time. If you set a timer that has not yet expired, that timer is simply reset to the new value

Where the timer kinds are real, virtual, and profiling (I want real time for all timeouts).  By "you", I assume they mean a given process.  My tests so far indicate that each subsequent call to `setitimer()` is effectively removing the old timer and installing the new timer alone.

How can I implement multiple timeouts (more than one per timer kind) in a manner functionally similar to `setitimer()`?  Ideally, it should be possible cross-platform, but if it matters my development environment is Ubuntu Linux and my target environment is Android.

Comment: `<thread>` and `<chrono>` ?

Comment: Try using [`timer_create()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/timer_create) instead of `setitimer()`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'd prefer to avoid the complexity of introducing my own multithreading code into the program, but thread/chrono look like the most customizable solution -- any tutorial links you'd recommend?

Comment: You might do something like: [Demo](https://ideone.com/Vce1yc)